# Can I delete Azure resources after creating an image?

Tags: virtual-machines, azure

I created a CentOS 7.4 VM named "base" on Azure. When the VM was created, the following resources

- base_Os_Disk_1_xxxx
- basexxx (Network Interface)
- base-ip (Public IP Address)
- base-nsg (Network security group)
- base (Virtual Machine)

Configured the VM as needed and created an image. The process deleted the VM named base and created a new resource named base-image-timestamp (Image).

However the other resources like disk, network interface, public ip, etc were not removed.

I can successfully create new VMs based off the image.

Can I now manually delete the resources that were initially created (base_OsDisk, base-ip etc) or are they needed for new VM creation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Correct. You can delete all the leftover resources. Azure does not delete it automatically for you because you may want to use it for new deployments, let say, keep the existing network configuration and public IP address instead of creating a new one for the new VM.

Just make sure to not delete the image.

Comment: I tried to reuse the IP address resource and it was grayed out. Will double-check.

Comment: Must be because it is associated with the old network card which still exists.